# Get the value of a prop of the before instance Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is possible to save the value of a prop in the data of the component for the next renderizing?
I mean, I want to update the data component from Vue and in the new instance get the value of a prop of the before instance

Comment: This sounds like you should use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or something similar and store that data in a store

Comment: I update my data app with powershell scripting every minute, I store the data in a .json file and my vue component get this data with axios. Now I want my component save the value of the data and when I update the data I can use the data of the frist .json and the data of the second .json

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated, re-rendering means just that...rendering again. :)
So the short answer would be no, you can not save prop value within a component and use it after re-rendering.

You say that every minute you are fetching some data that later on you will be doing some logic on. As suggested use Vuex for that, save that data before re-rendering and the use it as you like.

One of many Vue.JS good point is a very well written documentation. You need Vuex so here it is: https://vuex.vuejs.org/